# Passing complex object parameter to ObjectDataSource Select

Tags: c#, asp.net, objectdatasource

I am using an ObjectDataSource and I would like to pass a custom object as the select parameter.

Here is my DL method:

```
public static Collection<AdminUserEntity> GetUsers(ClientEntity currentClient)
{
}
```

So when I configure my ObjectDataSource I choose the AdminUserEntity as the buisness object to bind to and then choose GetUsers  as the Select method but as you see it takes a complex type as a parameter and I don't know how to specify this using the wizard or manually.

After some more digging I found this solution:

```
protected void ods_Selecting(object sender, ObjectDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
{
     ClientEntity currentClient = ClientEntity.GetClient("abc");
     e.InputParameters["currentClient"] = currentClient;
}
```

Are there any other ways to accomplish this or is this a good solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the bottom of this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57hkzhy5(v=vs.80).aspx

You'll want to use the DataObjectTypeName property on the ObjectDataSource control. This will be the name of the custom object.

Either solution should work just fine.

Comment: This works.  I was getting confused between the TypeName and the DataObjectTypeName property.  Thank-you.

Comment: @tdean I feel you, I did the same mistake